# JWT TOKEN Generate Client_Assertion

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, access-token

I am newbie in JWT access Token generation. I have Public Key, Private key and ClientID. I need to generate Client_Assertion.

client_assertion: JWT (signed by client ID, public certificate and private key using
RS256 as the signature algorithm).

I have found some Node.JS code but I want to do it using .Net Framework (Not .Net Core)
Node.Js code can be seen on [this link](https://kevinle.medium.com/securing-c-net-webapi-with-public-private-key-signed-jwts-signed-by-nodejs-4fd60d97b7f4)

I need to do it in C#. From where to start and how to achieve it?

Comment: I don't have time to provide a proper answer, but in ASP.NET Core you should looka t documentation and examples for this package: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;`
https://hbhhathorn.medium.com/authorize-with-jwt-in-asp-net-core-3-0-web-api-542d7a10e8f5

Comment: @AaronLS I need to do it in .Net framework not in .Net Core.

Comment: I am looking exactly for the same thing. Were you able to find something?

Answer (score 1):

I used the .NET libraries

- System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
- Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens

I'm also assuming that, as you said you have a private key, and that you've loaded that into an `RSACryptoServiceProvider`

Here's my sample code

First create your claims. This is your JWT payload

```
var claims = new Claim[]
{
    new Claim(MicrosoftJwt.JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "your subject"),
    new Claim(MicrosoftJwt.JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.Now.ToEpochSeconds().ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer),
    new Claim(MicrosoftJwt.JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60).ToEpochSeconds().ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer),
};
```

Then you need to configure your signing credentials using your private key.

```
// Assuming you already have your key loaded into an RSACryptoServiceProvider
var key = new MicrosoftTokens.RsaSecurityKey(csp)
var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);
```

Now you can create your token

```
var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
    issuer            : issuer,
    audience          : audience,
    claims            : claims,
    signingCredentials: signingCredentials
);
// You can add extra items to your Header if necessary
jwt.Header.Add("kid", deviceId);
```

You can then write your token to a string

```
var assertion = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);
```

I think the value of `assertion` is what you're trying to get

Comment: Got me going but would have helped if MicrosoftJwt and MicrosoftTokens usings had been included, initially I'd not realised they were usings. Also couldn't find ToEpochSeconds() in .NET 4.7.2, but was able to use DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds()